# HttpClient dependencies marked as duplicate

Tags: java, http, android-studio, gradle, dependencies

When i run an Android studio project, i get the following gradle output:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/NOTICE
File1: C:\Users\Benas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpclient-android\4.3.5.1\eecbb0b998e77629862a13d957d552b3be58fc4e\httpclient-android-4.3.5.1.jar
File2: C:\Users\Benas\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.httpcomponents\httpmime\4.3\5b0002c5fb66867ca919be0fbd86de1cfaf76da7\httpmime-4.3.jar
```

My build.gradle:

```
compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents' , name: 'httpclient-android' , version: '4.3.5.1'
compile('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3') {
    exclude module: "httpclient-4.3.jar"
}
```

How do i solve the duplicate entry problem?

Comment: might be related to this library `org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.2.4` try removing that

Comment: It works without it, but we need to have MultipartEntity class. If i remove this dependency, i don't get the class.

Comment: I updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for the duplicate Meta-Inf stuff all you have to do is add this to your gradle

```
packagingOptions {
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'
    exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this to solve problem:

```
packagingOptions{
exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
}
```